# FuelPHP database query error: Cannot access protected property

Tags: php, fuelphp

I'm a FuelPHP newbie and I have a query problem. So, this is my code:

```
$query = DB::query('SELECT * FROM `table`');
$result = $query->execute();
$totals = $result->_total_rows;
print_r($totals);
```

And i keep getting following error:
Fatal error: Cannot access protected property Fuel\Core\Database_MySQL_Result::$_total_rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the number of rows returned by a query simply

```
$query = DB::query('SELECT * FROM `table`');
$result = $query->execute();
// Just count the results, it returns an int.
$totals= count($result);
```

Referenced [here](http://docs.fuelphp.com/classes/database/usage.html#/results) in the manual

Or in your case, as you're selecting all from a table and counting it, you could use the following instead

```
DB::count_records('table');
```

Referenced [here](http://docs.fuelphp.com/classes/database/db.html#/method_count_records) in the manual

Comment: Thanks for a fast answer. The main thing I want to get here is actually _result. But it was a bit easier to make it with _total_rows. So, i want to get an array of results and I will loop thru in the view itself.